# Stopping time with alternating sign random variables

Tags: central-limit-theorem, martingale, optimal-stopping, stopping-time

I find myself trying to solve a peculiar stopping time problem. Let $\{X_i\}$ be set of continuous random variables of a stochastic process, each with finite mean value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. I am interested in finding the expected value of the stopping time $\tau$ given by:

$$\tau = \inf_n \left\{ \left| S_n \right| := \left| \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i\ X_i \right|>a\right\}$$

What is then $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$?

**Attempts:**

My first attempt was based on noticing that we can let $Z_i := X_{2i+1}-X_{2i}$ so that the sum over $Z_i$ is indeed a discrete-time martingale. This way, we can apply the Optimal Stopping Theorem to obtaing $\mathbb{E}[S^{Z}_\tau] = \mathbb{E}[S^{Z}_0] =  \mathbb{E}[Z_0] = 0$. The fact that this result equals $0$ prevents us from applying Wald's Theorem directly. Nevertheless, I am afraid that this way we are "missing information" in the sense that we are restricting $\tau$ to even values, which could potentially lead to a wrong result.

(*Side question:* why does none of the results I find about stopping time problems depend on the standard deviation $\sigma$ of $X_i$?)

I am relatively new to statistics and I am trying to learn all these new concepts on the way (first time working with martingales and OST Theorem), so I apologize if there is any missconception in what I did.

**Edit:** typo in the definition of $Z_i$

**Edit 2:** in my second attempt, I found an extension to Wald's second equality for independent but not-id variables that states:

$$\mathbb{E}[S_\tau^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum^\tau_{i=0}\sigma_i^2\right]$$

Since in this particular case we have that $\sigma$ is the same for all $X_i$:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\tau\right] = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbb{E}[S_\tau^2]$$

Now, what strategy can I follow in order to obtain $\mathbb{E}[S_\tau^2]$? Intuitively,

$$ \mathbb{E}[S_\tau^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{-a} dS_\tau S_\tau^2\ f(S_\tau) + \int_{a}^{\infty} dS_\tau S_\tau^2\ f(S_\tau) = 2\int_{a}^{\infty} dS_\tau S_\tau^2\ f(S_\tau)$$

For $f(S_\tau)$ the probability density function.

How can I solve this with not knowing the probability distribution of $X_i$? Is there any alternative approach?

Comment: The sum of $Z_i$ doesn't seem relevant to your problem, due to the telescoping, but summing over *even* values of $i$ is.

Comment: @whuber That was a typo, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case that $a = 1$ and $X_0 \sim U(1, 2)$ then with probability $1, S_0 > 1$ and so $E[\tau] = 0$. Now let's keep $a = 1$ and replace $X_0$ with normal distribution of the same mean and variance as $U(1, 2)$, which should be $N(\mu = 1.5, \sigma = \sqrt{1/12})$. Now $E[\tau]>P(X_0 \in [-1, 1]) > 0$

From this we can conclude that $E[\tau]$ depends on more than just $a, \mu, \sigma$ and you can't give an exact solution.

Now being given $\mu$ and $\sigma$ makes me think that you can construct an upper bound using Chebyshev's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality). I'm admittedly not entirely sure how.
Also i wrote a small simulation for a less clear cut case in R. Maybe it will help you make some further investigations:

````
n <- 10000 # number of simulations

a <- 1.5
# mu = 1 sig = 1
taus_normal <- replicate(n, {
  i <- 0
  S <- rnorm(1, 1, 1)
  while (abs(S) <= a) {
    i <- i+1
    S <- S + ifelse(i %% 2 == 0, 1, -1) * rnorm(1, 1, 1)
  }
  return(i)
})
# lambda = 1, therefore mu = 1 sig = 1
taus_poisson<- replicate(n, {
  i <- 0
  S <- rpois(1, 1)
  while (abs(S) <= a) {
    #print(paste("i:", i, "S:", S))
    i <- i+1
    S <- S + ifelse(i %% 2 == 0, 1, -1) * rpois(1, 1)
  }
  return(i)
})
mean(taus_normal)
mean(taus_poisson)
```
````

Comment: I'll take a deep look at this! Thank you very much!

Comment: This shows that $E[\tau]$ depends on more than $a,\mu,\sigma$ for small $a$ — but for larger $a$ it seems likely that whenever $X$ and $X’$ have the same mean and standard deviation, $$\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{E[\tau]}{E[\tau’]}\to 1$$